# What is 'Microsoft.PPIProjection'?

Tags: windows-10

There is a rogue entry in my Start menu called `ms-resource:ProductName`. When I right-click it and go into its settings, it seems to be an app called `Microsoft.PPIProjection`. What is this app for, is it important?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

it is either the local wireless display service or the windows stores remote app mount service.  Absolutly vital even if you don't use them.  Lock things down in group policies,  never delet preinstalled anything, just negate it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the answer is too inclusive. Windows is pre-bundled with adware, spyware, bloatware, time-limited test-ware, and games.
most of them are not required for valid operation.